# Spring Data (JPA) does not work with dates?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

something weird happens here ...

And I want to gel all fields using this query using JPQL or Spring JPA, **but both methods return 0 fields**.

```
SELECT * FROM puntuacion WHERE id_tienda = 1 
AND fecha BETWEEN <InitialDate> and <EndDate>;
```

I have this entity, look at "fecha" property

[image]

This is the code ... (I'm using Spring Boot, Spring MVC, and Spring JPA)

Controller ...

[image]

Service ...

[image]

Repository ...

[image]

Also, I tried something like this, but I got the same result.

```
    @Query("SELECT p FROM Puntuacion p WHERE p.isActive = 1 AND 
           p.idTienda = ?1 AND p.fecha BETWEEN '?2' AND '?3'")
    public List<Puntuacion> searchTiendaByDate(long idTienda,
    Date fechaInicio, Date fechaFin);
```

Obviously, when I query the DB it returns values.

[image]

What happens here ?

Comment: Please, edit your question and post your code as code, and not as pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just pass the Date value as a parameter to the DB and it works.

It's not necessary to parse twice the date, trying to match different Date formats. 
If you are using Spring JPA, just pass the Date value.